Benefit to using /kotlin/ instead of /java/ in a pure Kotlin project in Android Studio?
When creating a new package in Android Studio, it suggests a number of directory names including kotlin. This makes it seem like there is a point to having a /kotlin/ package. The default Android Studio creates, even if you select Kotlin in the setup wizard, is to put all the files in /java/ though.
What is the point of the /kotlin/ package? Is there a benefit to using it instead?

There hasn't been any functional difference between using src/main/java or src/main/kotlin to Kotlin Gradle Plugin in a long time.
The only benefit is for your own personal sanity to have some separation between .java and .kt source files.

There is some benefits of using /Kotlin/ instead of /java/ in pure kotlin project.

Organizational Clarity: It clearly separates kotlin code from java, making the project structure more intuitive.
Best Practices: It aligns with the community standards for Kotlin-only projects, enhancing the readability for other developers.
Maintainability: It simplifies navigation and maintenance as the project grows, which reduces the potential confusion.
future flexibility: It simplifies navigation and maintenance as the project grows, which reduces the potential confusion.

